# Can I have audio from my PC output to Bluetooth while my video outputs to AirPlay?

Tags: audio, video, bluetooth, appletv, airplay

As it stands, my Apple TV is hooked up directly via HDMI to my television. I have 2 amazing speakers that I use bluetooth to connect to and play from when I'm NOT using AirPlay. When I switch to AirPlay, the sound comes from my TV speakers which sound terrible, instead of my higher-quality bluetooth speakers.

Can I cast my MacBook's video stream via to the TV via AirPlay, while routing the audio through Bluetooth instead of my TV Speakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out -

1. Connect to AirPlay, so that both video and audio streams are going to the TV
2. Open System Preferences > Sound. Click "output" tab.
3. Select your bluetooth speakers.

Voila.